# Custom themes for mat-menu with Angular v15

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-theming

I'm stuck trying to make `mat-menu` apply my custom themes for Angular v15. Any related issue I find forwards me to the [official theming page](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming), to look at overlays.

All the while, there are no overlay details of any kind in v15 documentation, or anything pertinent to menu specifics.

Does anybody know how custom theming works for `mat-menu` in v15 of Angular? I know things have changed a lot in that department for v15, and everything I've tried so far didn't work.

P.S. Funny thing, they use it themselves on the [official documentation page](https://material.angular.io/), they just forgot to tell us how to implement it:

[image]

Comment: Not sure how to do this, but this is the source code for the theme picker. Just plain scss and nothing fancy with mixing themes: https://github.com/angular/material.angular.io/blob/main/src/app/shared/theme-picker/theme-picker.scss

Comment: @Felix I had no problem implementing my own theme picker, following official documentation. It's the `mat-menu` specifics that I am asking here about.